# How do you store state.Data and state.isValid in ADYEN Card Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, adyen

So I've read the documentation and have followed everything so far. However, in the handleOnChange function, I cannot post the data because it gives the error:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BUMG.png)

Here's how I'm currently trying to post the data, I'm open for any suggestions.

```
function handleOnChange(state, component) {
  state.isValid 
  state.data 
  component 
  if (state.isValid === true) {
    this.http.post(environment.paymentFunctionurl + '/', { amount: this.amount, content: state.data}).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
}
```

I've tried storing them as variables but it results as undefined. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is with accessing `http`, it isn't part of `this`. You need to make sure `http` is added to `this` or likely put http on `window` so you can access it regardless of your scope.

Side note: your example is passing `amount` from the client.

#### Do not do this in production!!!!

You might be just doing this while testing, but it's even bad practice in testing. A client may be malicious and change the amount and instead you should use your own backend/database to dictate how much to charge.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I've ran into another problem that I've been on for days. I'll be posting another question shortly,